# String not displaying properly on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm new here so forgive me if I've made a stupid mistake. I'm trying to edit this website (http://www.fountfornations.org/) and it looks the way I want it to on desktop, but when I look on mobile the line saying "empowerment without limitation" goes to the top and off the screen. How would I fix this issue? I've tried using a media query and moving the string down if screen size is <600px, but it makes no difference on the positioning of the string. Here is my code:

HTML:

```css
CSS:

    .motto{
 text-align: center; 
 padding-left: 60px;
 position: relative; 
 right: 155px;
 
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    ...
    #words{
 text-align: left;
    }
    .motto{
 position: relative;
 top: 250px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="motto">
    <h1>EMPOWERMENT <span style="color: #ffcc00;">WITHOUT LIMITATION</span></h1>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your text is jumping to the top because you are specifying a `top` value in the media query. Simply remove this to have it stay where it is vertically on the page.

You're using `right` to align your content by default, and `left` to align it in your media query. When you reach the snap-point, the `.motto` will have **both** attributes applied to it.

You shouldn't really need to use either `left` or `right` with `position: relative`, as you're already using `padding-left` on `.motto`. I'd recommend using **`margin-left`** instead of `padding-left` (so that the whole `.motto` moves, not just the `<h1>`, and change this on the snap-point to reach the desired indentation:

```css
.motto {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .motto {
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="motto">
  <h1>EMPOWERMENT
    <span style="color: #ffcc00;">WITHOUT LIMITATION</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Also note that you don't need to re-declare `position: relative` in the `@media` query, as elements within media queries will automatically inherit any non-media-query rules, so the element already has `position: relative` applied.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I tried this, but it still doesn't fix the issue :(